# Compare two df's and delete unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df's, one of which I want to only keep the most recent data, i.e df1 acts as a rolling record, and df2 feeds information to it.

If there is an ID appearing in df1 which isn't appearing in df2, I want to drop it from the new iteration of df1. All new ID's appearing in df2 should be added, and the duplicates should be kept.

Furthermore, I have a running count of the amount of appearances an ID has.

I have been trying to use df.join, I thought the outer method would have been appropriate.

Ideally I want something that's the opposite to df.drop_duplicates

This is my code so far:

```
grp1 = {'ID': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square']
        }

grp2 = {'ID': ['3','4','5','6','7'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(grp1, columns= ['ID','Shape'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(grp2, columns= ['ID','Shape'])

df1.loc[df1["ID"].isin(df2["ID"]), 'count'] += 1 

df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
```

The code I have written so far is this, however it is giving me the wrong output

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='ID',how='right')

output:

    ID  Shape_x  count_x    Shape_y count_y
0   3   Square    1.0      Rectangle    1
1   4   Rectangle 1.0      Rectangle    1
2   5   Square    1.0       Square      1
3   6   NaN       NaN      Rectangle    1
4   7   NaN       NaN       Square      1
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
df1
    ID  Shape        count
0    1  Rectangle      1
1    2  Rectangle      1
2    3     Square      1
3    4  Rectangle      1
4    5     Square      1

df2
    ID  Shape        count
0    3  Rectangle      1
1    4  Rectangle      1
2    5     Square      1
3    6  Rectangle      1
4    7     Square      1

ideal output:
    ID  Shape        count
0    3  Rectangle      2
1    4  Rectangle      2
2    5     Square      2
3    6  Rectangle      1
4    7     Square      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the similar [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) code for `df2`, as follows:

```
df2.loc[df2["ID"].isin(df1["ID"]), 'count'] += 1
```

**Data Setup**

```
grp1 = {'ID': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square']
        }

grp2 = {'ID': ['3','4','5','6','7'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(grp1, columns= ['ID','Shape'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(grp2, columns= ['ID','Shape'])

df1['count'] = 1
df2['count'] = 1

print(df1)

  ID      Shape  count
0  1  Rectangle      1
1  2  Rectangle      1
2  3     Square      1
3  4  Rectangle      1
4  5     Square      1


print(df2)

  ID      Shape  count
0  3  Rectangle      1
1  4  Rectangle      1
2  5     Square      1
3  6  Rectangle      1
4  7     Square      1
```

Then, run the new code:

```
df2.loc[df2["ID"].isin(df1["ID"]), 'count'] += 1
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)

  ID      Shape  count
0  3  Rectangle      2
1  4  Rectangle      2
2  5     Square      2
3  6  Rectangle      1
4  7     Square      1
```

### Edit

If you want to approach from `df1`, you can use:

```
grp1 = {'ID': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square']
        }

grp2 = {'ID': ['3','4','5','6','7'],
         'Shape': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(grp1, columns= ['ID','Shape'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(grp2, columns= ['ID','Shape'])

df1['count'] = 1
df2['count'] = 1

df1.loc[df1["ID"].isin(df2["ID"]), 'count'] += 1 

df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
```

This yield `df1`, as follows:

```
print(df1)

  ID      Shape  count
0  1  Rectangle      1
1  2  Rectangle      1
2  3     Square      2
3  4  Rectangle      2
4  5     Square      2
5  6  Rectangle      1
6  7     Square      1
```

Then, to filter out the rows where

> an ID appearing in df1 which isn't appearing in df2

we further use our handy friend [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) again:

```
df1.loc[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
```

This filters to keep only those `ID` in `df1` that is also in `df2`.

**Result:**

```
  ID      Shape  count
2  3     Square      2
3  4  Rectangle      2
4  5     Square      2
5  6  Rectangle      1
6  7     Square      1
```

Comment: How would I do this for df1 though? As in I want to drop the ID's from df1 that aren't reoccurring, add +1 for the duplicates as well as add the new df2 ID's

Comment: @Crocs123  Ok, let me revise it.  Advise you when ready.

Comment: @Crocs123  See the edited version above.  Please remember to accept the solution if this is what you want.  Seen you NEVER accepted anyone question you posted in the past.  However, it is the appreciation system in StackOverflow that question asker should accept a solution that works best for them as an appreciation for the answerer and also for courtesy.  Please observe this norm in this family.

Comment: @Crocs123  How's the edited solution works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you data in count varies, you can do it with aggregation:

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['ID', 'Shape']).sum().reset_index()
res = res.loc[res.ID.isin(df2.ID)]
```

It gives the following frame:

```
ID  Shape   count
2   3       Rectangle   1
3   3       Square      1
4   4       Rectangle   2
5   5       Square      2
6   6       Rectangle   1
7   7       Square      1
```